# Split text that is on the left and right of ":"?

Tags: regex, vb.net, text, split

So I have my text, let's say login-credentials, that look like that:

```
username:password
```

And now I want to split those into two separate strings.

Kinda like that:

```
Dim OldLogin As String = Textbox1.Text
*Code to split + turning into 2 string called User and Pwd*
Textbox2.Text = User
Textbox3.Text = Pwd
```

I know I could use Regex somehow, but to be honest I have no idea how to actually do that...

Thanks in advance for any help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: What's wrong with OldLogin.Split(':') ?

Comment: Please use String.Split(), so we don't have to answer two questions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need of Regex for this simple task. There is [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that, like this:

```
Dim OldLogin As String = Textbox1.Text
Dim parts() = OldLogin.Split(":"c)
Textbox2.Text = parts(0)
Textbox3.Text = parts(1)
```

`String.Split` divides the instance of the source string at the occurences of the splitting character and returns an array of the splitted parts.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I've searched for!

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to use regex for a simple [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)?

```
Dim userNameAndPassWord As String() = Textbox1.Text.Split(":"c)
Textbox2.Text = userNameAndPassWord.First()
Textbox3.Text = userNameAndPassWord.Last()
```